# How to interpolate a variable into an attribute?

Tags: html, pug

I need to display the correct image based on the variable userAccount.image which is a String containing the name of an image (ie "profile1.png"). I can't seem to figure out the syntax for passing variables into attributes in pug.

I looked at the documentation for pug and I believe I replicated the nearest example to my case with no luck.

```
script.
    var image = '#{userAccount.image}'
img(src="/images/" + image)
```

The console throws the following error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/images/ 404 (Not Found)
```

meaning the variable `image` is an empty string. However when I console.log(image) in the script it shows "profile1.png"

Comment: Even though I found a way around it, I am still interested if there is a way to do it without writing a js script.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way around it.

```
img(id="img")
    script.
        var imgTag = document.getElementById("img")
        var image = '#{userAccount.image}'
        imgTag.setAttribute('src', "/images/" + image)
```